# removeAllObjects and nil-ing NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, dealloc

This might get down votes.... but gotta ask.
when "deallocating" a mutable dictionary, you call `removeAllObjects` but can you just set it to `nil` instead? Would that have the same result?
Like when you dealloc an array you set it to nil. Can I do that to a mutable array instead of calling `removeAllObjects`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, **ignore the absolute `retainCount`.  It is useless.  See (the sadly gone web site here is the new one) http://sdarlington.github.io**.

Secondly, the *contents* of the dictionary do not impact the lifespan of the dictionary itself (unless one of the objects in the dictionary has a strong reference to the dictionary, creating a retain cycle).

Thus `removeAllObjects` is entirely orthogonal to the lifespan of the dictionary (retain cycle caveat does apply).

As well, when all strong references (ARC) to a dictionary are destroyed, the dictionary will be deallocated and, in that process, all hard references from the dictionary to the objects it contained will be released, too.

I.e.:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKey:@(1),@"one"];

NSDictionary *doct = dict;

dict = nil;   // nothing happens

[something consumeDict:doct];

dict = nil;
```

On that final `dict = nil;`, the dictionary *might* be destroyed.  Or not.   It might not be destroyed immediately because `consumeDict:` caused a strong reference somewhere or because `consumeDict:` called `retain` then `autorelease` and the dictionary will stick around until the pool is drained.

Speaking of pools, sometimes, `[NSDictionary dictionary]` returns an *autoreleased* object.   So, sitting in the debugger, and checking whether the dictionary was released immediately after setting `dict` to nil (maybe through a __weak reference) is going to lead to sorry.   And note that +dictionary may sometimes return an autoreleased object or sometimes it won't depending on compiler optimization level or version.

Comment: That 'whentouseretaincount dot com' link is some kind of virus or trojan, commandeering the browser, forbidding it from closing, and trying to install software on my Mac.

Comment: @LogicsaurusRex Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

RemoveAllObjects does not deallocate a dictionary. It just remove all key-values from that dictionary. You can set new key-values without initializing it again. But setting it to nil means you need to initialize it again before inserting new values.

Comment: Ah I see now. So setting it to nil does deallocate it or does it not?

Comment: Yes nil means it's deallocating.

Comment: It doesn't.  Under ARC it removes a reference to an object.  The object won't deallocate until all references to it are removed.

Comment: remove reference is other thing than removing all objects from dictionary. If we remove all objects from dictionary but have a global variable that keeps it alive, dictionary won't be de-allocated.

Comment: My point is removing a reference is not the same as deallocating the object.

Comment: Yes you are right. If it has more than one reference count, then nil does not de-allocate it.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. If you remove your reference to the dictionary (whether it's mutable or not), and the reference count of the dictionary object reaches 0, the dictionary will get dealloced and thereby release all references to the objects it previously held. The objects of the array will likewise be dealloced if their reference count reaches zero.

All this happens automatically with ARC, and so you just have to worry about not keeping any references to the array objects in your code to make sure they get dealloced.

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array]; //1 reference to the array
NSMutableArray *anotherReference = arr; //2 references to the array
arr = nil; //there is still 1 reference to the array, so it is not dealloced
anotherReference = nil; //no references left and the array is dealloced
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Wait but according to user345095 even when you remove all objects of an array it wouldn't be deallocated unless you set it to nil. What am I missing

Comment: I've elaborated on my answer to show how retainCount works :) The amount of objects in the array has nothing to do with when it will be dealloced

Comment: The absolute retain count is useless.  Do not consider it.  You should only worry about whether you are incrementing or decrementing the retain count (or, in ARC, whether you hold a strong reference).   Example;  *technically* the retain count of `arr` may be 2 after that first line of code (in ARC).  May be?  Yes;  depends on compiler version and optimization level.   http://www.whentouseretaincount.com

Comment: I updated the answer to not mention retainCount specifically. I still believe it's useful to talk about the amount of references to an object to be able to conceptualize whats going on.